# How to lock down Ubuntu linux so that only the active user can log in

Tags: login, remote-desktop, account-restrictions

I am new to linux and interested in only allow in login via direct access to the machine (active user). I don't even want to be able to log in remotely myself. Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to do this? I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Ubuntu doesn't allow anyone to log in remotely – you'd need to install a server for that (for example, for an SSH server, the `openssh-server` package), and then activate it.

So, unless you're explicitly doing that, nobody can log in remotely.

If you already did install such a server, you can either uninstall it (`sudo apt remove {name of the server package}`, or just disable it (`sudo systemctl disable --now {name of the service}`, for example `sudo systemctl disable --now sshd`). But again, this will not be necessary unless you specifically set up a server first.